# React-Native - Create an animation select card

Tags: react-native

please help me
Currently, I want to create an animation for selecting card (as the attached image).
I would like to describe the animation:

- You can swipe left or right to select a card.
- "Click/hold or drag"  & the card will fly to the corresponding position
  Anyone who has any idea, a support library, or a demo pls contact me.
  Thank you all very much.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fls4n.jpg)

Comment: I think you are looking for this : https://github.com/mjinkens1/react-native-circle-list

Comment: Thanks alot Tushar Pandey, you are grande!!! I will research following ur direction